# geth --rpc - has latest blocks, but never terminates

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization

I'm running "geth --rpc" for the first time.  It ran overnight, and the next day it shows the block chain number matches the number on https://ethstats.net, but the program never stops running.  Looks like it is keeping up with the blockchains created all the time...

Am I supposed to CNTL-Break out of it, or just let it keep running forever while I got start trying to run ETHMINER in another command prompt window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are solo mining, you must run geth all the time.  ethminer connects to geth to find out what to mine.

If you are mining with a pool, you don't need geth at all.  ethminer connects to the pool to find out what to mine.

Comment: Ok, I think that makes sense.  The instructions I was following said to run it, and I thought a read some blogs about it running "a while" but not forever.

Comment: Oh, and I was using a pool, so that's a good bit of info to know too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

geth needs to be running in order to get the latest blockchain data.